# Runtime instantiation in scala without type parameters

Tags: scala, reflection

So here's what I have:

```
type CompType = Manifest[_ <: Component]

type EntityType = HashSet[CompType]
type CompSet = HashSet[Component]

val type_map = new HashMap[String, EntityType]
val entity_map = new HashMap[EntityID, CompSet]

def createEntityType(type_name: String) = {
  val ent_id = new EntityID
  val ent_type: CompSet =
    type_map(type_name) map (c_type => c_type.erasure.newInstance())

  entity_map += (ent_id -> ent_type)

  ent_id
}
```

But as you can see, the `map` function doesn't create a `CompSet`, it creates a `HashSet[Any]`.

Is there any way of solving this problem?

The whole point is to save object types for instantiation at a later time within the program, but I can't get this to work, and all the examples of reflection expect some kind of type parameter to cast to via `_.asInstanceOf[SomeClassType]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
type_map(type_name) map (c_type => c_type.erasure.newInstance().asInstanceOf[Component])
```

?

BTW, `Manifest` is deprecated in 2.10, you should use `ClassTag`s and `TypeTag`s instead.

Comment: Is there any way to ensure each instance is instantiated as whatever child of `Component` it is? Also, thank you I'll look into `ClassTag` and `TypeTag`.

Comment: If your `Manifest` contains information for a real class and not for `Component`, then this will be the case. `asInstanceOf` is just a type cast, it does not magically make `newInstance()` return an instance of base class, especially when it is impossible (if `Component` is an interface or an abstract class).

Comment: In retrospect, that makes sense. I've got it working thanks to your answer at least. I'll experiment with `ClassTag' and `TypeTag` before asking anymore questions right now. Thank you.